# Getting only the last element of the list in the for loop python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

I need to to traverse multiple folders in order to get the csv files which I finally need to add to a df. In the below code,only the csv files of the last folder are being added to the df. Can you please tell me why this is happening and how it could be solved? I am new to python, so any suggestions to optimize or improve the code will also very helpful.

```
for x in os.listdir(path):
       for y in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x):
            if "FP" in y :     
                for z in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y):
                    final_data = []
                    if "Frequency" in z:
                        columns =["frequency", "amplitude", "phase","axis","machinenumber","time"]
                        list_files = []
                        
                        for csv_files in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y +"\\" + z):
                            old_path = (path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y +"\\" + z + "\\" + csv_files)
                            #print(csv_path)
                            df = pd.read_csv(old_path,header=None,names=columns)
                            df["axis"].fillna(str(csv_files.strip(".CSV")),inplace = True)
                            df["machinenumber"].fillna(str(x.split("_")[1]),inplace = True)
                            df["time"].fillna(str(y.split("-")[2]),inplace = True)
                            list_files.append(df)
                        final_data = pd.concat(list_files)
                        final_data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\subhvaru\Desktop\1234.csv',index= False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line rewrites the file.
You can try to append to it so it does not delete existing content.

```
final_data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\subhvaru\Desktop\1234.csv', mode='a,index= False)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
columns =["frequency", "amplitude", "phase","axis","machinenumber","time"]
list_files = []
    
for x in os.listdir(path):
       for y in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x):
            if "FP" in y :     
                for z in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y):
                    if "Frequency" in z:                            
                        for csv_files in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y +"\\" + z):
                            old_path = (path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y +"\\" + z + "\\" + csv_files)
                            #print(csv_path)
                            df = pd.read_csv(old_path,header=None,names=columns)
                            df["axis"].fillna(str(csv_files.strip(".CSV")),inplace = True)
                            df["machinenumber"].fillna(str(x.split("_")[1]),inplace = True)
                            df["time"].fillna(str(y.split("-")[2]),inplace = True)
                            list_files.append(df)

final_data = pd.concat(list_files)
final_data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\subhvaru\Desktop\1234.csv',index= False)
```

Comment: Avoid posting answers with only code and no context so that others can better understand it.